# Arakelov Theory and Arakelov curves

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

There exists a definition of Arakelov Curve in Arakelov theory?

My question is because Neukirch (Algebraic Number Theory, Chapter III) defined Arakelov divisors in the set $X=Spec(\mathcal O_K)\setminus \{0\}\cup \{infinite\ primes \ of \ K\}$.

$K$ is a number field

Thank you all.

Comment: Not in the sense in which you are thinking probably. One can consider arithmetic surfaces $X\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ and then consider Arakelov line bundles on this surface. This is a 'curve' (it's relative dimension $1$), but we always want things over $\mathcal{O}_K$ and thus to be a smooth curve is to be an unramified extension of $latex K$. So, over $latex \mathbb{Q}$ there are no 'curves'.

Comment: It's wrong thinking that $X$ is a Arakelov curve?

Comment: No, I don't think wrong is the right word. It's just that if you define it to be a curve, then the only other reasonable 'curves' are the number rings of unramified extensions.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Two things: the OP didn't ask about *smooth* curves necessarily; and the analogue of being a smooth curve would typically just be the requirement of that the underlying scheme be regular, so Spec $\mathcal O_K$ would satisfy this for any ring of integers.  (Think about the role of *regular* models of curves over number fields; these are analogous to smooth surfaces --- e.g. they satisfy the same basic set of results, such as Castelnuovo's criterion, and factorization of birational maps into blow-ups and blow-downs.)  In any case, if $\mathcal C$ is the regular model of a curve ...

Comment: $C$ over a number field $K$, and $P$ is a closed point of $C$, then the Zariski closure of $P$ in $\mathcal C$ will be the Spec of an order in the residue field of $P$, and I would usually think of this Zariski closure as being an "arithmetic curve" in the "arithmetic surface" $\mathcal C$ (and I think this is a fairly common intuition).  To make things more Arakelov-y, one could also think about the behvaviour of $P$ in the archimedean fibres of $\mathcal C$.

Comment: @tracing Ah, I see! That's a good point!

Answer (score 0):

The term "arithemetic curve" was coined by Shouwu Zhang in his landmark paper "Positive line bundles on arithemetic surfaces" (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2946601). See page 4-5 of the paper. In most cases you may think about it as a horizontal divisor in an arithemetic surface.

The notion is later generalized by Zhang to *arithemetic variety* of any dimesnion.